# provide jquery script that won't interrupt client's page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've got a script started that I will need to offer my customers.  The idea is that they drop a line of code in their web page and my script does what it needs for them. (in this case, all it is doing is loading content into a div; an image with a link)

so..the customer drops in a `<div id="name_of_div"></div>` and a script tag pointing to this:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}

if ($('#name_of_div').length) {
        $('#name_of_div').load('[content url]');
    };
}
```

I'm pretty sure this roughly works how I'd like, however, I've been reading some things about "never do things globally" and something about putting this stuff inside a function so it doesn't encroach on the page's DOM.. do I have that right?

I'm thinking I can enclose in a function to guarantee my own scope...but what other steps should I take to make sure my script, when included into someone else's page, doesn't block or mess with anything already existing?

Secondly, is it better to use jquery.load() or a simple iframe?

thanks

Comment: I think this would be more fitting on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the code into a function is one step toward isolating it.  Putting it into an anonymous and [immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) is the next step.  Consider this:

```
(function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
        jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
    }

    if ($('#name_of_div').length) {
        $('#name_of_div').load('[content url]');
    }
})();
```

Nothing outside of that function can see its internals, so it doesn't pollute global scope.  (Just be sure not to, for example, create values on the `window` object within that function.)  The function is created and immediately executed (note the parentheses at the end), allowing it to just do its thing and be done.

If there are further interactions that would need to take place, such as exposing an API for your users, then you can *return* the API object from that function.  Something like this:

```
var yourAPI = (function () {
    var someAPIFunction = function () {
        // some piece of functionality a user may call later
    };

    return {
        someAPIFunction = someAPIFunction
    };
})();
```

Now the user can create that `yourAPI` object and put it in whatever scope he would like.  It exposes only what you want it to expose, and the rest of your internal work is simply performed and completed that one time when the page loads.